# How create a loop of expression and logical operators by loop - javaScript?

Tags: javascript, loops

If I have An array of value and I want to create logical operators while I do a loop over these values

```
const values = [{from: 2, to: 8}, {from: 11, to:20} ..... ]
```

to get a result like this

```
return (8 > 2) || (20 > 11) || .......
```

How I can do this with javascript if I want to create something complex like

```
   const time = [{ from: '2021-07-30', to: '2021-07-20' }, { from: '2021-07-05', to: '2021-07-02' }, ......]
    const disableDates = (date) => {

        time.forEach(element => {
            return (moment(date).isSameOrBefore('2021-07-30') && moment(date).isSameOrAfter('2021-07-20')) || (moment(date).isSameOrBefore('2021-08-05') && moment(date).isSameOrAfter('2021-08-02')) || .....

        });

    }
```

I want to create this line

```
return (moment(date).isSameOrBefore('2021-07-30') && moment(date).isSameOrAfter('2021-07-20')) || (moment(date).isSameOrBefore('2021-08-05') && moment(date).isSameOrAfter('2021-08-02')) || .....
```

Comment: What have you tried? Start with a loop over the array and then within that loop, access the object properties and begin writing your conditional statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
const values = [{from: 2, to: 8}, {from: 11, to:20}];
console.log(values.some(x => x.to > x.from));
```

EDIT Base on new spec. Using [moment.isBetween](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/)

```js
const time = [{ from: '2021-07-30', to: '2021-07-20' }, { from: '2021-07-05', to: '2021-07-02' }];
const disableDates = (testDate) => time.some(x => moment(testDate).isBetween(x.to, x.from, undefined, '[]'));
console.log(disableDates('2021-07-25'));
console.log(disableDates('2021-07-02'));
console.log(disableDates('2020-01-01'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function f() {
    // some instructions

    for (let v of values) {
        if (v.from < v.to) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const values = [{ from: 2, to: 8 }, { from: 11, to: 20 }]

var isOk = false;
values.forEach(v => isOk = isOk || (v.from < v.to))
console.log(isOk)
```

Comment: If I want to create something more complex like :     const disableDates = (date) => {

time.forEach(element => {
  return (moment(date).isSameOrBefore('2021-07-30') && moment(date).isSameOrAfter('2021-07-20')) || (moment(date).isSameOrBefore('2021-08-05') && moment(date).isSameOrAfter('2021-08-02'))

});
        
    }